# How to output particular lines of code in C++

Tags: c++

I have just finished learning C++ on my own (no outside help, just through a few website tutorials) and now I am currently working on my own mini project. The project is just a basic bank account system that registers a user (asking the user their account number, name, and current balance)

Here is what I did so far. I have created a text file called "BankAccount.text" and right now it contains the following:

**Welcome to your banking account**

Your account number:

Your First Name:

Your Last Name:

Your current balance:

Your account number: 1

Your First Name: ftest

Your Last Name: ltest

Your current balance: $10

My question is, how do I output the particular line of text to the user who wants to see their information, for example, a user is asked to enter their account number (say 1, like above), and the program outputs the four lines (1, ftest, ltest, $10)

Here is my code (i won't show the entire thing):

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int accnum; //account number of user
string fname; //first name of user
string lname; //last name of user
double balance; //balance amount of user


void show_record()
{
    cout << "Enter your account number: ";
    cin >> accnum;

    /*
    ifstream bnkacct("BankAccount.text"); //needed to read the bank account information file

    if(!bnkacct) //if we couldn't open the output file for reading
    {
        cerr << "Sorry, we could not open your bank account information. We are sorry for the inconvenience" << endl;
        system("pause"); //needed, or else the program will end right away
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (bnkacct)
        {
            string strInput;
            getline(bnkacct, strInput);

            cout << strInput << '\n';
        }
    }
    */
}

int main()
{
    cout << "**Banking account information system**" << '\n';
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Select one of the options below" << '\n';
    cout << "1: Add record to file" << '\n';
    cout << "2: Show record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "3: Search record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "4: Update record information" << '\n';
    cout << "5: Delete record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "6: Exit options" << '\n';
    cout << "\n";

    int option;
    cout << "Enter an option: ";
    cin >> option;

    cout << "\n";

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        add_record();
        break;
    case 2:
        show_record();
        break;
    default: //else if the user did not enter either of the following options
        cout << "You must enter the following options specified!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    system("pause"); //needed if using Visual Studio, else the program ends immediately after program is run

    return 0;
}
```

So how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Keep track of what information is on what line(s), for example, then read lines from the file 1 at a time, using a counter to keep track. If the counter matches a number you need to display, output it. Else skip over it.

Comment: Read the entire text file into a `vector` of `struct` containing the account information and then simply do a look-up by either name or account number and output the information contained in the matched struct. Your self-learning seems to have overlooked ***validating all user input***, e.g. `if (!(cin >> option)) { cerr << "error: invalid input.\n"; /* handle error */ }` See [std::basic_istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (e.g. `good, eof, fail, bad`)

Answer (score 0):

@David C. Rankin has the right idea. I put together a basic implementation for you. It does pretty much no error checking, data validation or anything clever so keep in mind there is a lot of room for improvement here. But it works and should give you something to go on.

```
struct AccountDetails
{
    string fname; //first name of user
    string lname; //last name of user
    double balance; //balance amount of user
};

void show_record(std::map<int, AccountDetails> bankRecords, int accountNumber)
{
    auto itr = bankRecords.find(accountNumber);
    AccountDetails detailsToDisplay;
    if (itr != bankRecords.end())
    {
        detailsToDisplay = itr->second;

        cout << "Account number: " << accountNumber << '\n';
        cout << "Your first name: " << detailsToDisplay.fname << '\n';
        cout << "Your last name: " << detailsToDisplay.lname << '\n';
        cout << "Your balance: " << detailsToDisplay.balance << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<  "Sorry, we could not open your bank account information. We are sorry for the inconvenience." << endl;
    }
}

std::map<int,AccountDetails> ReadRecords(string fileName)
{   
    std::map<int, AccountDetails> records;
    ifstream bankFile(fileName);
    string accountNumber;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string balance;

    AccountDetails temp;

    if(bankFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!bankFile.eof())
        {
            getline(bankFile, accountNumber);
            getline(bankFile, firstName);
            getline(bankFile, lastName);
            getline(bankFile, balance);

            temp.fname = firstName;
            temp.lname = lastName;
            temp.balance = atof(balance.c_str());

            records.emplace(atof(accountNumber.c_str()),temp);
        }   
    }
    return records;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "**Banking account information system**" << '\n';
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Select one of the options below" << '\n';
    cout << "1: Add record to file" << '\n';
    cout << "2: Show record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "3: Search record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "4: Update record information" << '\n';
    cout << "5: Delete record from file" << '\n';
    cout << "6: Exit options" << '\n';
    cout << "\n";

    int accountNumber = INT_MAX;
    int option;
    cout << "Enter an option: ";
    cin >> option;
    cout << "\n";

    std::map<int,AccountDetails> bankRecords = ReadRecords("BankAccount.text");

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:     
        cout << "Enter your account number: ";
        cin >> accountNumber;
        show_record(bankRecords, accountNumber);
        break;

    default: 
        cout << "You must enter the following options specified!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```